# How can I sell time slots using drupal Commerce?

Tags: views, datetime, commerce, javascript

I want to allow customers to purchase products for a specific time slot and within a date range. Can this be done?

I want to achieve the following.

1. Allow products to be sold within a certain date range.
2. Also allow products to be sold for a certain time within that date range, for example between 1200 and 1300 or 1200 and 1220.
3. Show availability of those dates / time slots on a calendar for people to choose from.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are looking for [Commerce Booking](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_booking):

> This module provides tools to use Drupal Commerce as a powerful event booking system. Any entity can be an 'event' and a single booking can contain any number of tickets.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I have tried the Commerce Booking module but I can't achieve what I want with it. It's also very sparse on documentation which does not help.